# The name '_dictionary' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

The name '_dictionary' does not exist in the current context
and dictionary is declared but is saying not available in current context

```
public  class HTTPCokie
{
  private Dictionary<string, string> _dictionary;
  public HTTPCokie()
  {
      _dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  }


  public string this[string key]
  {
      get { return _dictionary(key); }
      set { _dictionary(key) = value; }
  }

}
```

Comment: You are calling a method named `_dictionary(key);` and the compiler is saying it is not declared. Compiler is right because I do not see it either.

Answer (score 2):

When accessing `Dictionary` elements you should use square brackets syntax:

```
public string this[string key]
{
    get { return _dictionary[key]; }
    set { _dictionary[key] = value; }
}
```